# Adding data to jquery $.cache / using data() without a dom element

Tags: jquery

I often use jquery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method instead of creating global variables. Usually, i attach them to my `<body>`-tag.

But is there any way to skip the dom element? Would it be a bad idea to do something like `$.cache['foo'] = 'bar';`?

Comment: Why do you want to skip the element?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that other than the data will not be automatically emptied in the same way that data on an element gets removed when the element gets removed. (probably not as relevant with the body tag)

Comment: @karim79 I want something that works in IE7.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sometimes I create global variables that has nothing to do with a dom element, hence I would prefer not attaching it to one.

Comment: @Johan then you may want to rethink your design because reliance on global variables is usually bad...